# physical meaning of laplace-beltrami eigenfunctions?

Tags: eigenfunctions

The eigenfunctions of Laplace-Beltrami operator are often used as the basis of functions defined on some manifolds. It seems that there is some kind of connection between eigen analysis of Laplace-Beltrami operator and the natural vibration analysis of objects. I wonder, is my intuition true? What is the physical meaning of Laplace-Beltrami eigenfunctions?

For now, I only know that the eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator are real and orthogonal, thus they could be used as the basis of functions on the manifold where the functions are defined.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47497/2451

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eigenfunctions of the Laplacian can be used to construct solutions to differential equations involving the Laplacian, most notably the [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation), the [heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation), and the [Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation). The wave equation gives the collection to oscillation; Laplacian eigenfunctions describe standing wave solutions and their eigenvalues describe the period of the oscillation.

See also [hearing the shape of a drum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum).