# Probabilistic Interpretation of Laplace-Beltrami Spectrum

Tags: probability, differential-geometry, stochastic-processes, riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory

Given a Riemannian manifold, $(M,g)$, the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenfunctions $\phi_i$ of the associated Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_g$ can be used to construct the heat kernel on the manifold, as well as solve the wave and Schrodinger equations (e.g. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264480/physical-meaning-of-laplace-beltrami-eigenfunctions)).

There are some interesting probabilistic facts about these constructs:

- On the manifold, the infinitesimal generator of Brownian motion is $\Delta_g/2$ (e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694227/what-is-the-importance-of-the-infinitesimal-generator-of-brownian-motion))
- The heat kernel (i.e. the smallest positive fundamental solution to $\partial_t u = \Delta_g u$) serves as the transition density function of Brownian motion on the manifold (e.g. see [Heat Kernel on a Non-Compact Riemannian Manifold, by 
  Grigor’yan](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~grigor/cornall.pdf)), and can be written via a spectral decomposition as:
  $$
   p(x,y,t) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \exp(-t\lambda_i)\phi_i(x)\phi_i(y)
  $$

My question is whether there are other stochastic interpretations of the Laplace-Beltrami operator. In particular, do the eigenvalues and eigenvectors themselves have any kind of probabilistic interpretation on their own?